# currency stating which country first

Tags: php, script

I have just realized that my site has somehow started displaying a products price with 'US' infront of it. I am not sure why all of a sudden its doing this never the less is there a way to quickly change this?

Comment: What page exactly?

Comment: @VernardLuz Every page.

Comment: Hard to replicate. Any clues that might be responsible for this change? It can be configuration, installation of an extension, etc.